# How to extract specified row from excel without NaN

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlrd

Why am I getting "raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))" with this code?

I want to extract specified row and col from excel file without NaN.

```
readFile = 'testFile'
input_book = pd.ExcelFile(readFile) 
df_list = []

for sheet in input_book.sheet_names:
    df_list.append(input_book.parse(sheet)) 
    for d in df_list:
        print(d.dropna(subset=['test1', 'test2']))
```

And here is the data(separated cells in each | ).
The Index is column which is I create myself.

---

```
Index | test1   | test2 | test3

1     |apple   | stone  | Red

NaN   |banana  | stone  | Blue

NaN   | orange | stone  | Yellow  

  2   |  kiwi  | stone2  | White

NaN   | cake   | stone2  Black
```

---

And I want to do this.

---

```
Index | test1  | test2

1     | apple  | stone  

2     | kiwi   | stone2
```

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback of the exception.

Comment: Is `Index` is column or Index itself?

Comment: @CharlieClark Thank you for replying. I edited explanation please see above.

Comment: @pygo The Index is column which is I create myself.

Comment: @LisaGo - then need `print(d.dropna(subset=['Index','test1', 'test2']))`

Answer (score 1):

If `Index` is column add it to list:

```
for d in df_list:
    print(d.dropna(subset=['Index','test1', 'test2', 'test3']))
```

If need remove missing values from all columns:

```
for d in df_list:
    print(d.dropna())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I'm sorry I miss posted that I forgot to add column 'test3'.
I want to extract also without column 'test3'.

Also I tried your code but this outputs same error as explanation.

Comment: Your code worked well but it's only for a sheet or a file. I got KeyError when I try to use this for multiple sheets. So I use your code each files or sheets. Thank you for your answer.